# Get the original Timezone from Postgres tstz field

Tags: java-8, postgresql-9.5

I am having a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE tstz (
    ts timestamp NULL,
    tstz timestamptz NULL,
    seq text NULL
);
```

Whenever, I store the timestamp with time zone, it gets converted to the timezone of the database. How do I get back the original timezone with which it is retrieved?

For example, I am storing the timezone like 2020-04-29T08:06:03.424689+05:30 to the database. However, when I read the database using Java and read the timezone again like following.

```
 Optional<Tstz> tstzOptionalSaved =  tstzRepository.findById(tstz.getSeq());
        Tstz tstzSaved = tstzOptionalSaved.get();
        log.info("Timezone  {}" , tstzSaved.getTstz().getZone().getId());
```

the above code always returns UTC which is the timezone of the database.

Is there a way to do this in Postgres or in Java?

Comment: The original time zone is not stored in that value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is no way we could do that?

Comment: You can't retrieve information that isn't stored

Comment: what data type are you using to map the column in your domain class `Tstz` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OffsetDateTime`. From [postgresql docs](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html),

> all OffsetDateTime will instances will have to be in UTC (have offset 0). This is because the backend stores them as UTC.

So you need to add one column for offset and then use the offset to get original value,

```
OffsetDateTime tstz = rs.getObject("tstz", OffsetDateTime.class);
OffsetDateTime odtOriginal = tstz
        .toInstant()
        .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(rs.getInt("tstz_offset")));
// 2020-04-29T08:06:03.424689+05:30
```